# Character changes when importing to Access and exporting to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm working on an Access database in which I import csv files converted from xls 
Usually this works, but recently one file has some fields where characters change within the field after being imported into Access

For example: 
a dash changes to û
a beginning double quote changes to ô
an end double quote changes to ö

From what I have read it has something to do with 7 or 8 bit  character codes.. which is not something I really understand.

My questions are, is there any way to prevent this character change or is there something better than what I've tried already? 
Or are there any potential problems that I haven't come across with what seems to work in my example below?

Here's what I've tried so far that seems to work

From the original Excel file Save as unicode text file (something new for me)

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _ 
"D:\NewFiles\ReportList.txt", FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText _ 
    , CreateBackup:=False
```

Then import into the database with the following code

```
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "ReportList  Import Specification", "tbl_ReportList", "D:\NewFiles\ReportList.txt", True
```

This seems to import the text into the database correctly.

Other people work with the data and then export a new report from Access to Excel. 
That changes the font to MS Sans Serif and changes the characters again but not the same changes as when it was imported. 
After the Excel report is exported, and I change the font to Arial the characters are correct again.... at least so far.

I haven't run into this character change in the past and my solution seems to work, but I'm not sure if there are other potential problems or if there's anything I missed.  I haven't found the answer to this specific question yet.

Thanks for taking time to help with this.

Comment: I've run in to this before, but admittedly it's not my area of expertise, either.  I have some functions laying around that *might* be helpful for opening/reading/writing UTF8 encoded files in to memory, but not in to the worksheet/workbook.  I can provide those if you're interested, but first, try [this method](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=154957&p=560424#post560424) to convert TXT encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that I have used in the past to circumvent the character encoding issues.

I suspect this method should also work between Excel and Access -- although Access is not really something I am familiar with.

This sub specifies the file's full name & path, and a destination for a new filename & path. These could be the same if you want to overwrite existing.

**NOTE** On a few simple tests, I can't get this to read a file saved  as "Unicode" from Excel, but it works perfectly on files saved as "Tab Delimited TXT" files and CSV/comma-separated files, too.

```
Sub OpenAndSaveTxtUTF8()
Dim txtFileName as String
Dim newTxtFileName as String

txtFileName = "D:\NewFiles\ReportList.txt"
newTxtFileName = "D:\NewFiles\UTF8_ReportList.txt"

WriteUTF8(ReadTextFile(txtFileName), newTxtFileName)

End Sub
```

This sub calls on two functions which I borrowed from sources credited in the code comments. The `WriteUTF8` creates a proper UTF8 file from the contents of `ReadTextFile` which returns a string of the full file contents.

```
Function ReadTextFile(sFileName As String) As String
'http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=699
    Dim iFile As Integer

    On Local Error Resume Next
     ' \\ Use FreeFile to supply a file number that is not already in use
    iFile = FreeFile

     ' \\ ' Open file for input.
    Open sFileName For Input As #iFile

     ' \\ Return (Read) the whole content of the file to the function
    ReadTextFile = Input$(LOF(iFile), iFile)

    Close #iFile
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

This function requires a reference to the ADODB library, or, you can `Dim objStream As Object` and the code should still work for you.

```
Function WriteUTF8(textString$, myFileOut$)
'Modified from http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=42375
'David Zemens - February 12, 2013

'Requires a reference to ADODB?

     ' UTF8()  Version 1.00
     ' Open a "plain" text file and save it again in UTF-8 encoding
     ' (overwriting an existing file without asking for confirmation).
     '
     ' Based on a sample script from JTMar:
     ' http://bytes.com/groups/asp/52959-save-file-utf-8-format-asp-vbscript
     '
     ' Written by Rob van der Woude
     ' http://www.robvanderwoude.com

    Dim objStream As ADODB.Stream

     ' Valid Charset values for ADODB.Stream
    Const CdoBIG5 = "big5"
    Const CdoEUC_JP = "euc-jp"
    Const CdoEUC_KR = "euc-kr"
    Const CdoGB2312 = "gb2312"
    Const CdoISO_2022_JP = "iso-2022-jp"
    Const CdoISO_2022_KR = "iso-2022-kr"
    Const CdoISO_8859_1 = "iso-8859-1"
    Const CdoISO_8859_2 = "iso-8859-2"
    Const CdoISO_8859_3 = "iso-8859-3"
    Const CdoISO_8859_4 = "iso-8859-4"
    Const CdoISO_8859_5 = "iso-8859-5"
    Const CdoISO_8859_6 = "iso-8859-6"
    Const CdoISO_8859_7 = "iso-8859-7"
    Const CdoISO_8859_8 = "iso-8859-8"
    Const CdoISO_8859_9 = "iso-8859-9"
    Const cdoKOI8_R = "koi8-r"
    Const cdoShift_JIS = "shift-jis"
    Const CdoUS_ASCII = "us-ascii"
    Const CdoUTF_7 = "utf-7"
    Const CdoUTF_8 = "utf-8"

     ' ADODB.Stream file I/O constants
    Const adTypeBinary = 1
    Const adTypeText = 2
    Const adSaveCreateNotExist = 1
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

    On Error Resume Next

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Open
    objStream.Type = adTypeText
    objStream.Position = 0
    objStream.Charset = CdoUTF_8


'We are passing a string to write to file, so omit the following line
'    objStream.LoadFromFile myFileIn

'And instead of using LoadFromFile we are writing directly from the COPIED
' text from the unsaved/temp instance of Notepad.exe
objStream.WriteText textString, 1

    objStream.SaveToFile myFileOut, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    objStream.Close
    Set objStream = Nothing

    If Err Then
        WriteUTF8 = False
    Else
        WriteUTF8 = True
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```